# Insert data in mongodb using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

i am developing simple chat application and i want to store messages in mongoDb.
but i am getting error when i run this code. 
can not read property '_id 'of undefined. i already create one collection call chat.

```js
var MongoClient= require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert=require('assert');
var ObjectId= require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var bodyParser= require('body-parser'); 
var express = require('express'),
  app=express();
  server=require('http').createServer(app),
  io= require('socket.io').listen(server),
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
  var mongo=require('mongodb');
  users = {};
  url='mongodb://localhost:27017/anant';

server.listen(9000, function(){
 var host= server.address().address;
 var port=server.address().port;

 console.log("save app listen on http://%s:%s", host , port);
});

/*var server = app.listen(9000, function(){
 var host= server.address().address;
 var port=server.address().port;

 console.log("save app listen on http://%s:%s", host , port);
});*/


app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
 socket.on('new user', function(data , callback){
  if(data in users){
    callback(false);
  }else{
   callback(true);
   socket.nickname= data;
   users[socket.nickname]= socket;
   updatenicknames();
  }
 });
 
 io.sockets.on('send request', function(data , callback){
   var name=data;
   console.log(data);
 });


 socket.on('send message', function(data , callback){
  var msg=data.trim();
  if(msg.substr(0,3) === '/w '){
    msg = msg.substr(3);
    var  ind = msg.indexOf(' ');
    console.log(ind);
    console.log("got it after ind ");
    if(ind !== -1)
    {
     var  name=msg.substr(0, ind);
     var msg=msg.substring(ind + 1);
     console.log(name);
     console.log(msg);
     if(name in users){
      console.log("got it in if name condition");
      users[name].emit('wishper', {msg: msg , nick: socket.nickname} );
     console.log('whisper..! ');
     } else
     {
      callback("enter a vlid user");
     }
    } else{
      callback('please enter message for your wishper');
    }
  }else {
  insertData(data);
  io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: msg , nick: socket.nickname} );
  } 
 }); 

 function updatenicknames(){
   io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
 }

 function insertData(data)
 { 
 
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
   console.log(data);
   db.collection('chat').save(data.msg , (err,result)=>{
    if(err){
     console.log("not inserted");
    }else {
     console.log("inserted");
    }
   });
  });
  
 }
 socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
  if(!socket.nickname) return;
  delete users[socket.nickname];
  updatenicknames();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are passing a **string** `data`, to your `insertData` function (judging by your code, I guess you are supposing that `data` is actually an **object**).

Then you are giving `data.msg`, which is obviously `undefined`, as the first argument of the `save` methods, which is expecting you to provide a valid **object** here.

Please also note that you are using the `save` method on a newly created document, instead of using `insertOne`.

As you can see in the [api documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#save), using `save` is now deprecated. (I guess you are using the last version which is currently 2.1)